# Is this C multithreaded tcp server correct?

Tags: c, multithreading, sockets, semaphore, tcpserver

I created a multithreaded C TCP server. It seems to work (as a client I type a message and the message is sent to the server and the server prints what the client sent in a thread (and send back the client id).

Do I respect the "best practices" of a C multithreaded TCP server ?
Maybe I should use a semaphore to access / use the client_counter variable ?

```
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <string.h>

#include <unistd.h> // disable close() warning
#include <sys/socket.h> 
#include <sys/types.h> 
#include <netinet/in.h> 

#include <pthread.h>

#define MAX_CONNECTIONS 5

static int client_counter = 0;

void* serverWorker(void* context)
{
    char client_response[256];

    int sock = *(int*)context;
    char message[256]  = "\n Hello dear client, you are the client number \n";
    char numero[12];
    sprintf(numero, "%d", client_counter); // SHOULD I USE A SEMAPHORE HERE FOR client_counter ?

    while(1)
    {
        memset(client_response, 0, sizeof(client_response)); // clean string
        recv(sock, &client_response, sizeof(client_response), 0);
        printf("client number %s sent: '%s' \n", numero, client_response);
        if (send(sock, numero , strlen(numero) , 0) < 0)
        {
            printf("ERROR while sending response to client from worker \n");
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}



int main() 
{ 

    printf("Waiting for incoming connections ...\n");

    // socket creation 
    int server_socket;
    server_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    // dserver address
    struct sockaddr_in server_address;
    server_address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_address.sin_port = htons(9002);
    server_address.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

    // bind the socket to IP and port
    bind(server_socket, (struct sockaddr*) &server_address, sizeof(server_address));

    listen(server_socket, MAX_CONNECTIONS);

    int client_socket;
    while((client_socket = accept(server_socket, NULL ,NULL)))
    {
        client_counter++; 
        pthread_t thread_id;
        pthread_create(&thread_id, NULL, serverWorker, (void*)&client_socket);
        printf("new client ! \n");
    }

    close(server_socket);

    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: One problem is that you pass all the threads the a pointer to the very same variable. While in most cases that will work (since the threads will copy it) there might be cases where two threads could get the same value for the socket. The `pthread_create` and its thread argument pointer is one of the very few cases where passing an actual *value* (properly casted to `(void *) (intptr_t)`, and then back as `(int) (intptr_t)`) is considered okay.

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com ...

Comment: @hyde It's important to note that it's for *working* code only.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude OK so you mean I shouldn't pass "&thread_id" this way as the first parameter of the pthread_create function ?

Comment: No no no, not the `thread_id` variable, the *thread function **argument***, the socket. Pass it as `(void *) (intptr_t) client_socket`. Then in the thread function do `int sock = (int) (intptr_t) context;`

Comment: OK @Someprogrammerdude thank you very much :-)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Indeed, but according to question text, this code "seems to work", there is no actual problem to solve.

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems in your code... you create a thread on an incoming connection and pass all the created threads a reference (the same reference) to the variable in which you have stored the socket descriptor.  This will make all threads to share the same variable to store all the socket descriptors you'll get from the wildcard one.  Probably you think *well, i make a copy just on thread start, so this is not going to happen*, but think two connections that come in almost simultaneously, thread `main()` runs and processes both.  Then the first and second threads get scheduled and **both** get the same descriptor stored (the second one) and the first connection is leaked.

Another thing is that while this variable is local to main, it will cease to exist as soon as `main()` returns (which is not the end of the program, if the threads are to survive past `main()`'s `return`)  but as you are in an endless loop (you probably don't know, but the only means for the `server_socket` to give an error is if you destroy (`close()` it) in a thread, or you drop the interface it is attached to.)  This could lead to a `SIGSEGV` trap.

You can freely pass an `int` value casted to `(void *)` without problem, as the thread body function will convert it back to an `int` before use, which reduces to a noop at all, as pointer types are normally greater in size (or equal, but not lesser) than  `int`.  Anyway, this is strictly *undefined behaviour*, but probably that will work (as legacy software is full of such conversions, so all compilers normally implement to try to respect this) The right way to do this is to declare a `struct` of information to be passed to the thread on start and return from it.  Then you can store on it whatever you want, but think that, as you have a dynamic amount of threads to come, you need the structs to be dynamically allocated.

In respect to the use of the `client_counter` variable, the only thread touching that variable is the one running `main()` code.  This plants no major problem than the risk presented above, two updates in quick sequence can make both threads to get the values updated in main after main has made both updates.

Another issue is that you need to declare it `volatile` as the thread code will not assume it is only changed by it between accesses and will probably cache it as a register variable.

The messages passed between `main()` and the different threads you are getting can be implemented in two ways.  This is the reason of the routines to get a `void *` on input and returning a `void *` on return:

- The first uses a dynamic `struct` of local data (`malloc()`ed, passed from `main()` to the thread, and back on termination, (when you join the thread to main).  This way allows you to collect result info from the thread in main and then you have to `free(3)` the struct in main.  The struct is used as a communication message between the thread and the main routine in both directions, and you can store there any information you need to pass or to return back.  Once the thread has finished, you can `free()` the structure in main (don't do it in the thread, as it has to survive its death)
- The second involves no more communication with `main()` and the threads must deallocate the structure, once it is finished.  This is simpler, and more adequate to your example.  In this way, you can destroy the struct in the thread, or in main, but only if you have already joined the thread and are sure the struct is not going to be used by it.

Answer (score 0):

One common mistake is that you do not examine the return values of `send` and `recv` calls. These calls may send and receive less then the entire buffer and such cases must be handled, as well as disconnects. That will also remove the need to use `memset` and `strlen` on received data.

Generally, dedicating a thread to each client is considered non-scalable. You may like to read the famous [The C10K problem](http://www.kegel.com/c10k.html) for a good treatment of I/O strategies for handling many clients. The article is old but the advice is timeless.